# tar: Cannot read: Is a directory in docker

Tags: tar, docker

I want to add an archive (`.tar.gz`) and unpack it during image creation using a Dockerfile.

```
ADD archive.tar.gz /archive.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf archive.tar.gz
```

When I want to unpack the archive, I get following message:

```
tar: /archive.tar.gz: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

which doesn't make any sense to me, since the file `archive.tar.gz` is not a directory.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After running an intermediate commit of the docker image I could see, that `/archive.tar.gz` indeed is a directory.
This means that docker automatically extracts archives when adding them during image creation.

Now I could also find this documented in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add).

(edit: files, e.g. `.sql.gz`, are not decompressed on adding)

Comment: "If <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory." - wow, really strange thing :D Thanks for the information!

Comment: I don't know, how to actually add an archive file if you need it as file in the docker then …

Comment: Have you tried to add the complete folder which contains the archive file?

Comment: It actually was just a hypothetical question, which popped to my mind :-) But now I had to check it and: If you add a folder containing archive files, the archives will currently not be unpacked.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the archive to remain as is use `COPY`, not `ADD`.

Answer (score 1):

For others who have run into this problem more recently when referencing *remote* urls with their `ADD` commands, this is a problem with Docker `17.06.0-ce (2017-06-28)`.

From [Dockers release notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/17.06/#17060-ce):

> Note: Docker 17.06.0 has an issue in the image builder causing a change in the behavior of the ADD instruction of Dockerfile when referencing a remote .tar.gz file. The issue will be fixed in Docker 17.06.1.